# can i move to another activity via spinner?

Tags: android, android-intent, spinner

i search all over for similar solution but find nothing;
is it possible to move to en another activity with spinner?
i tried to simply start explicit intent from switch case but it doesnt work

this is my code:

```
//add new movie spinner and callback
    ArrayList<String> addOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
    addOptions.add("Add manually");
    addOptions.add("Add via web");
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,addOptions);
    addMovieSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    addMovieSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long i) {

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Edit.class);

                break;
            case 1:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Home.this, Edit.class);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just creating an Intent won't move to another Activity. You need to actually **launch the Intent** with `startActivity()` like this:

```
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Edit.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 1:
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Home.this, Edit.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```